# Impact of other Nakshatras which are not the birth-nakshatra on an individual

Tags: astrology, nakshatra

I understand that each individual has a nakshatra which is based on the date of birth of an individual. I want to know do other nakshatras (other than the birth nakshatra) have any impact on an individual? Or is it always one individual to one nakshatra connection?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is impact of all the nakshatras on Jataka, because most important thing about nakshtra is their lord and which Grahas are in that nakshtra.
Giving a simple example if Budh graha risiding in the nakshtra which is 1st, 2nd, 3rd from your Lagna naskshtra(ascendent), Jataka will go through bad Mental state throughout his life, considering other planet also matches with this *Yoga*.

Effects of *Nakshtra* is very **vast** subject.
one of the books to go through for detailed understanding of nakshtras.

Jataka Bharanam

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. You have mentioned about 1st, 2nd and 3rd ascendant nakshatra. So can it be assumed that only 4 Nakshatras can impact an individual? The remaining 23 nakshatras will not have any impact?

Comment: @Sanjay read my answer again i am saying it is one of the lots of yogas, You got it completely wrong lets say your Budh is in Rohini nakshtra, and your ascendent i.e (Lagna) is Ashwini this yoga will get applied provided other planet position meets this situation. And this is one of the few Yogas and there are different effect when each planet resides in different Nakshatra with respect to your ascendent(lagna) Nakshtra. 

It is not to be taken literally as you are asking only 4 Nakshatras affecting it is not like that.